# Decorations using \draw inside axis environment

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw vectors normal to curved surface using pgfplots. Here's my MWE and result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{test/.style={
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.0 and 0.1 step 0.01
        with { \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (0,-5); }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=50, ymax=50,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1]
\addplot[smooth cycle, test] coordinates {
    (0.0, 0.0)
    (20.0, 15.0)
    (40.0, 30.0)
    (0.0, 40.0)};
\end{axis};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I however change axis limits, for example setting

```
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-20, ymin=0, xmax=50, ymax=50,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1]
```

I get the following output:

[image]

I also get similar behavior by setting some data coordinates to negative values, for example

```
\addplot[smooth cycle, test] coordinates {
    (0.0, 0.0)
    (20.0, 15.0)
    (40.0, 30.0)
    (-20.0, 40.0)};
```

The question is how to properly use \draw to decorate inside pgfplots axis environment?

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates in the decoration settings need a relative coordinate system, `axis direction cs` (or `rel axis cs`). The default coordinate system are absolute coordinates with  `axis cs`.

```
\draw[-latex] (axis direction cs:0,0) -- (axis direction cs:0,-5);
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{test/.style={
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.0 and 0.1 step 0.01
        with {
          \draw[-latex] (axis direction cs:0,0) -- (axis direction cs:0,-5);
        }
    }
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-20, ymin=-5, xmax=50, ymax=50,
    % xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=50, ymax=50,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1]
\addplot[smooth cycle, test] coordinates {
    (0.0, 0.0)
    (20.0, 15.0)
    (40.0, 30.0)
    (0.0, 40.0)};
\end{axis};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]